# HTML Elements not displaying accordingly. Why is this happening?

Tags: html, css

Why is it displaying like that?

```css
body {
  margin: 0 200px;
}

h1 { font-size: 16px; }
```

```html
<h1>hi</h1>
<h1 style="float: left">hello</h1>
<h1 style="float: right">BYE</h1>
<h1>THIS IS A NEW LINE PLEASE</h1>
```

I just need it to display accordingly. This has never happened before. I dont have a clue

Comment: you need to clear float property

Comment: what do you mean clear? i need the float there

Comment: What is your expectation? It is unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: hello and bye will float left and right and anything on the bottom should just be normal

Comment: THIS IS A NEW LINE should be below the previous code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to avoid float. Flexbox has much smart way to handle this problem

```css
.floatwrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0 200px">
    <h1>hi</h1>
  <div class="floatwrap">
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <h1>BYE</h1>
  </div>

    <h1>THIS IS A NEW LINE PLEASE</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes just flex will slove your problem but if you want to maintain the alignment for left and right space between property will help you to align your text. play with it. i hope you will love flexbox :D

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the [`clear` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear), which puts the element after any floated elements.

```html
<div style="margin: 0 200px">
    <h1>hi</h1>
    <h1 style="float: left">hello</h1>
    <h1 style="float: right">BYE</h1>
    <h1 style="clear: both">THIS IS A NEW LINE PLEASE</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, really freaked out there for a second